# R Convert and split string to date and time?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have the following structure of my datetime column in my df dataframe:

YYYYmmddhhmmss, for example: "20171204211500".

I have tried using split and substring, is there any way to do it fast and efficient?

And I have checked the site for similar questions but it's not the same.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `as.POSIXct` to convert to a Date time object

```
out <- as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
out
#[1] "2017-12-04 21:15:00 IST"
```

From this, we can convert to `Date` object with `as.Date`

```
as.Date(out)
```

and also extract the time component with `format`

```
format(out, "%H:%M:%S")
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "20171204211500"
```

Comment: as.POSIXct("20171220175000", format = "%Y%d%m%H%M%S")
[1] NA

Comment: why the as.POSIXct("20171220175000", format = "%Y%d%m%H%M%S") [1] NA returns NA?
This is what happening in my column, all nulls

Comment: @steves In your string, there are 3 0's at the end, while the OP have all 20s at the end

Comment: sorry but can you clarify? Look:
as.POSIXct("20171220175000", format = "%Y%d%m%H%M%S")
[1] NA
> str1 <- "20171204211500"
> as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y%d%m%H%M%S")
[1] "2017-04-12 21:15:00 IDT"

Why first doesn't work, but the second do work?

Comment: Check the format of your data. In the this case you use `20171220175000` with `format = "%Y%d%m%H%M%S"` - so you are looking for the 20th month which does not exist.

Comment: @akrun would you be so kind and tell me how can I extract time in Hours:Minutes format? I have seen that it's not supported for some reason. I have used chorn/lubridate but all return with seconds.

Comment: @steves You can extract it as a character i.e. `format(out, "%H:%M")#[1] "21:15"` .  Suppose you need it to do some calculation, then use the `times` from `chron` to have Hours:Minutes:Seconds format and then format it later after the calculation

Answer (score 2):

Use lubridate package

```
library (lubridate)

date<- "20171204211500"
date_ok <- ymd_hms(date)
date_ok
[1] "2017-12-04 21:15:00 UTC"
```

Any doubts, just tell me

Comment: What is fecha? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry fecha is `date`

Comment: `date_ok <- ymd_hms(date)`